# Manipulating an algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This came in a competition, I went back home and tried it but was unsuccessful.

If $$\frac{a^3+3ab^2}{3a^2b+b^3} = \frac{x^3+3xy^2}{3x^2y+y^3}$$ then -

$$1) ~ax =by
~~2)~ xy = ab
~~3)~ ay = bx
~~4) ~ax = b$$

It is clear that if the following given condition holds for the variables then there would be a case in which $a  = x$ and $b = y$. Hence then options should also satisfy this and hence **we can eliminate options a and d**. But I was not able to solve the question further. I tried adding and subtracting 1 from both sides but found nothing helpful.

Moreover **we are required to show if the correct option is sufficient to show that the first condition is true for the given variables.**

Answer (score 2):

Apply componendo-dividendo on this :
$$\frac{a^3+3ab^2}{3a^2b+b^3} = \frac{x^3+3xy^2}{3x^2y+y^3} $$

To get :

$$\frac{(a+b)^3}{(a-b)^3}=\frac{(x+y)^3}{(x-y)^3}$$

$$\implies \frac{(a+b)}{(a-b)}=\frac{(x+y)}{(x-y)}$$
Now apply reverse componendo-dividendo to get $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac xy$$

That is :
$$\color{blue} {ay=bx}$$

---

Componendo-dividendo is :

If you have the ratio $$\frac pq =\frac rs$$ Then you can add $1$, and subtract $1$ (In both, LHS and RHS) and take the ratio of two equations thus formed to get $$\frac{p+q}{p-q}=\frac{r+s}{r-s}$$

Comment: So on the right hand side you added 3x^2y+y^3 to the numerator and x^3+3xy^2 to the denominator. I don't see how that is algebraically "legal".

Comment: Clever, I have not seen this before. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Have you read the book higher algebra by hall and knight?

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal Is there any doubt in applying C-D ?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{a(a^2+3b^2)}{b(3a^2+b^2)}=\frac{x(x^2+3y^2)}{y(3x^2+y^2)}
$$

Define

$$\alpha=a/b,\;\;\;\chi=x/y$$

$$
\frac{\alpha(\alpha^2+3)}{3\alpha^2+1}=\chi\frac{\chi^2+3}{3\chi^2+1}
$$

The function

$$
f(x)=x\frac{x^2+3}{3x^2+1}
$$

is increasing (a.e.), that is if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Since the original equation you gave reads $f(\alpha)=f(\chi)$ we can conclude that $\alpha=\chi$ or in terms of $a,b,x,y$:

$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y}
$$

cross multiplying

$$
ay=bx
$$

Comment: So basically you're saying that in $f(x)$, for every $x$ there would be a unique value of $f(x)$ since the function is constantly increasing?

Comment: Also what about the second part of my question? Is it sufficient to show the given condition?

Answer (score 0):

$$0=\frac{a^3+3ab^2}{3a^2b+b^3} -\frac{x^3+3xy^2}{3x^2y+y^3}=$$
$$=\frac{(ay-bx)(3a^2x^2+3b^2y^2+a^2y^2+b^2x^2-8abxy)}{(3a^2b+b^3)(3x^2y+y^3)}=$$

$$\frac{(ay-bx)(3(ax-by)^2+(ay-bx)^2)}{(3a^2b+b^3)(3x^2y+y^3)},$$
which says that $ay=bx$ or
$$(ax-by)^2+(ay-bx)^2=0.$$
In the last case we  obtain $ay=bx$ again.

Thus, the answer is $ay=bx$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $$\frac{a^3+3ab^2}{3a^2b+b^3} = \frac{x^3+3xy^2}{3x^2y+y^3}\tag 1$$ as 
$$\frac{ ({a \over b})^3+3{a \over b}}{3({a\over b})^2+1} = \frac{({x \over y})^3+3{x\over y}}{3({x\over y})^2+1} \tag 2$$ and set $t={a\over b},\; s={x\over y}.$ Then
$$0=\frac{t^3+3t}{3t^2+1}-\frac{s^3+3s}{3s^2+1}=\frac{(t-s)\left[(t-s)^2+3(ts-1)^2\right]}{(3t^2+1)(3s^2+1)}.$$ Consequently $t=s,$ which is ${a \over b} = {x \over y},$ or $$ax=by \tag 3.$$

**Sufficiency**
Assume $ax=by.$ If $b\neq 0 \neq y,$ then clearly $(2)$ holds and $(1)$ follows.
 However, $ax=by$ is true if $b=0=y$ as well, but  $(1)$ is not defined.